# How to prevent line breaks in this case ? HTML

Tags: html, css

[How browser shows "my" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYvJV.png)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> chatter|app </title>

        <style>
            .styled_dates {
                font-size: 11px;
        
            }
        </style>
    
    </head>>
<body>
    <h1> chatter|app </h1>
    
    <h2> Favorites </h2>
    
    <p> <strong>Neversea</strong> <p class="styled_dates"> 11/07/2022 </p> 
    <p> <strong>Deutschland</strong> <p class="styled_dates"> 23/05/2019 </p>
    <p> <strong>Erasmus</strong> <p class="styled_dates"> 23/06/1999 </p>
    <p> <strong>Work</strong> <p class="styled_dates"> 04/07/2003 </p>

    <h2> Regular </h2>> 
</body>
</html>
```

Hello. Noobie here.

*What I want to do*:  see the dates next to "Neversea, Deutschland, Erasmus, Work", not underneath them.

```
Neversea  11 07/2022
```

not...

```
Neversea
11/07/2022
```

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: If you don't want a new paragraph, don't use a paragraph element!!

Comment: What **were** you expecting `<p> <strong>Neversea</strong> <p class="styled_dates"> 11/07/2022 </p>` to do? It's got two `<p>` tags in it. Take out the second one, or change it to a `<span>`.

Comment: You HTML is invalid, you have paragraphs (`<p>`) without closing tags (`</p>`).

Comment: there is an extra <p> on each line, or a missing </p>

Comment: There's also an error in `<h2> Regular </h2>>` - an extra `>`. You should consider using an IDE that will catch these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `<p>` tags by default follow onto the next line. Also you have unclosed tags (each line you open 2 and only close 1)

In my code I use `<span>` elements, they are made for in-line styling/changes which seems appropriate for your use case.

```css
.styled_dates {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<h1> chatter|app </h1>
<h2> Favorites </h2>
<p>
  <strong>Neversea</strong>
  <span class="styled_dates">11/07/2022</span>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Deutschland</strong>
  <span class="styled_dates">23/05/2019</span>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Erasmus</strong>
  <span class="styled_dates">23/06/1999</span>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Work</strong>
  <span class="styled_dates">04/07/2003</span>
</p>
<h2> Regular </h2>
```